# Delay a transition in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

How can I delay a transition? I want to click on a button and then a view should transition with a delay.

I have the following code but it is not properly synchronized.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showOne = true


    var body:some View{
        VStack{
            if showOne{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("One")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .animation(Animation.default.delay(2))
                .background(Color.red)
                .transition(.slide)
            }else{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Two")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .animation(Animation.default.delay(1))
                .transition(.slide)
            }
            Button("Toggle"){
                withAnimation(){
                    self.showOne.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you would like delay (postpone) it? Please, specify what should to be done and in which order, after pressing toggle button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add an explicit `id` it works as you would like.  Note, I made only one animation delay to make it a little more obvious that this is working.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showOne = true
    var body:some View {
        VStack {
            if showOne {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("One")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .id("one")
                .animation(Animation.default)
                .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Two")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .id("two")
                .animation(Animation.default.delay(2))
                .transition(.slide)
            }
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showOne.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found an explicit `id` to be helpful most of the time I want to use a transition.  In your example, not using the `id` can cause the text to change before the background.  This would seem to be a bug, and I recommend filing feedback on it.

Comment: Okay it took me forever to find out where my solution is broken. When you replace the `HStack` with two different views, the animation is broken again. Do you know how to fix it? I created a new question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464094/broken-animation-swiftui