# Broken Animation SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I initially had this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60271061/6594394). The solution proposed by @arsenius was working for this toy example. However, my application is more complex and it took me forever to find out where the animation breaks. In the example I used two animated `HStack`. But if I replace these `HStack` with **two different (!)** custom views, the animation is broken again.

Here is the code:

```swift
class State:ObservableObject{
    @Published var showSolution = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state:State

    var body:some View {
        VStack {
            if state.showSolution{
                CustomToggleOne()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .id("one")
                    .animation(Animation.default)
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                CustomToggleTwo()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .id("two")
                    .animation(Animation.default.delay(2))
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomToggleOne: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var state:State

    var body:some View{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action:{
                withAnimation {
                    self.state.showSolution.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Next")
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomToggleTwo: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var state:State

    var body:some View{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action:{
                withAnimation {
                    self.state.showSolution.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Next")
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

I added an instance of `State` to the ContentView in `SceneDelegate.swift` as an `EnvironmentObject` as follows:

```swift
let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context).environmentObject(State())
```

The expected animation can be seen when we use `CustomToggleOne()` twice in the `ContentView` instead of `CustomToggleTwo()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the approach that is correct, some explanations below and in comments. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

[image: demo]

*Reminder: don't test transitions in Preview - only on Simulator or Device*

```
// !! Don't name your types as API,
// State is SwiftUI type, might got unpredictable weird issues
class SolutionState:ObservableObject{
    @Published var showSolution = false
}

struct TestBrokenAnimation: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state:SolutionState

    var body:some View {
        VStack {
            if state.showSolution{
                CustomToggleOne()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .id("one")
                    .transition(.slide) // implicit animations confuse transition, don't use it
            } else {
                CustomToggleTwo()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .id("two")
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> public func withAnimation<Result>(_ animation: Animation? = .default, 
>               _ body: () throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
> ```

as it seen `withAnimation` is not state, which just activate animations defined via modifier, it explicitly applies specified animation, own, so having more in modifiers will definitely result in some conflicts.

So using *only* explicit animations with transitions.

```
struct CustomToggleOne: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var state:SolutionState

    var body:some View{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action:{
                withAnimation(Animation.default.delay(2)) {
                    self.state.showSolution.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Next")
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomToggleTwo: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var state:SolutionState

    var body:some View{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action:{
                withAnimation() {
                    self.state.showSolution.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Next")
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```